# How to group in cross-tab report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crosstab, crystal-reports-2010

I created a cross tab that shows the number of hours that employees worked each week. but I want to group them by their team leaders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a group for the team leader.  Move the crosstab into the new group's header.  It's going to be difficult to get the group-name field to be positioned where you want it reliably.  I would recommend creating a second group-header section (insert section below) and moving the crosstab to it.  So, GHXa would have the group-name field and GHXb would have the crosstab.

Comment: Thank you very much craig, it's work fine, but just a little problem , I don't know why for each group it's create a report in a new page, How to do If i want to create several reports on the same page if I still have a space in the current page .

Comment: Perhaps you are forcing a new page in the group's footer.  Clear the 'new page after' setting.

Comment: I'm sorry but in the group footer I set the properties KeepTogether to true AND newPageAfter to false but nothing has changed, but anyway thank you.

Comment: Just One more question, this the last one. If I want To group by two field like If I want to group my employees by their team_leaders and by their status (if they are a permanent employees or Temporary)

Comment: Two options.  1: grouping on a formula field that concatenates the values.  2: add another group (permanent|temporary) and move the fields from the parent group to the new child.

Comment: Check the header and ensure that there isn't a similar setting (new page before).

Comment: Sorry but I don't have any idea how to do that in crystal report, can you give me an exemple please ??? Here is a picture that shows the exmple : http://stream.tutowall.com/pic/Untitled.png. The name of the Team-leader in the picture is CLAFOND, he has 5 employees , 3 temp and 2 permanent